# List Intersect returning null

Tags: c#, linq, list, fileinfo, intersect

I have two `List<FileInfo>` and I want to return the common `FileItem` between them.

```
List<FileInfo> outputList = new List<FileInfo>();
outputList = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

However, I'm getting back an empty List.

Both the lists contain `FileInfo`'s found by

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = 
dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And filtered by queries.

Comment: `FileInfo` does not override `Object.Equals` so different instances will not be equal even if they refer to the same file. You will have to provide your own `IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>` to do the comparison.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that `FileInfo` doesn't override `Equals`/`GetHashCode`, so two distinct objects will be unequal even if they refer to the same file. Three options:

- Convert the lists to paths if you don't need them as `FileInfo`
- Create an `IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>` and pass that to `Intersect`
- Implement `IntersectBy` in the same style as `DistinctBy` in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) and propose it as a patch to the project :) (I thought we already had it, but apparently not...)

Comment: There is an example of exactly OP's situation and an example `IEqualityComparer` on [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546137.aspx) article.

Comment: @Bridge: Well, it's not a "good" example of `IEqualityComparer` IMO - that `GetHashCode` implementation is nasty :(

Comment: I only meant the article was a good example, I didn't say the `IEqualityComparer` was a good example! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The *references* to the `FileInfo` objects in your two lists will be different, and therefore `Intersect` will produce an empty list.

You would need to create a class that implements the [`IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) interface and pass an instance of this class to `Intersect` in order to get the result you expect.